# Why is Google Analytics not showing visits to this page (and goals)?

Tags: google-analytics

I checked my Google Analytics goals and I noticed it was at 0%, which I knew to be wrong. Going into the settings:

[image]

It seems to be correctly set up, for when someone visits the `/thank-you/` page, but when I tried to verify it, it should the goal at 0%. Using the real time version of Google Analytics and visiting that page shows it is working:

[image]

And if I look at the visits, there have been a few to that page:

[image]

Why is the goal not working?

Answer (score 1):

Goal verification is an indicator only, based on the past 7 days of data. If the amount of data is too small then verification may not work as expected.

Keep in mind too, if you are testing the page as a goal conversion via real time reporting, if you test it more than once within the same session, only the first time you hit the page will count as a goal conversion. Clear your cookies to end the current session if you want to retest it.